# How to Auto Increment Alpha-Numeric value in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.3

I am using `"PostgreSQL 9.3.5"`

I have a **Table**(`StackOverflowTable`) with **columns** `(SoId,SoName,SoDob)`.

I want a `Sequence generator` for column `SoId` which is a Alpha-numeric value.

I want to auto increment a Alpha-Numeric Value in postgresql.

```
For eg : SO10001, SO10002, SO10003.....SO99999.
```

**Edit:**

If tomorrow i need to generate a Sequence which can be as `SO1000E100, SO1000E101,...` and which has a good performance. Then what is the best solution!

Comment: If **all** values **always** have the prefix `S0` I would not generate that value at all. I would rather use a `serial` column and a view that formats the generated (numeric) id in the way you want it. Requires less space and less overhead to generate the number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use sequences and default value for id:

```
postgres=# CREATE SEQUENCE xxx;
CREATE SEQUENCE
postgres=# SELECT setval('xxx', 10000);
 setval 
--------
  10000
(1 row)

postgres=# CREATE TABLE foo(id text PRIMARY KEY 
                                    CHECK (id ~ '^SO[0-9]+$' ) 
                                    DEFAULT 'SO'  || nextval('xxx'), 
                            b integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into foo(b) values(10);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into foo(b) values(20); 
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# SELECT * FROM foo;
   id    | b  
---------+----
 SO10001 | 10
 SO10002 | 20
(2 rows)
```

Comment: It might be simpler to use `START [ WITH ] 10000` instead of separate `setval('xxx', 10000)`.

Answer (score 7):

You can define default value of your column as a concatenation of `S` and a *normal* `sequence` as bellow:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_for_alpha_numeric
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;


CREATE TABLE table1
(
  alpha_num_auto_increment_col character varying NOT NULL,
  sample_data_col character varying,
  CONSTRAINT table1_pkey PRIMARY KEY (alpha_num_auto_increment_col)
)
;

ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN alpha_num_auto_increment_col SET DEFAULT TO_CHAR(nextval('sequence_for_alpha_numeric'::regclass),'"S"fm000000');
```

**Test:**

```
                          ^
insert into table1 (sample_data_col) values ('test1');
insert into table1 (sample_data_col) values ('test2');
insert into table1 (sample_data_col) values ('test3');

select * from table1;
 alpha_num_auto_increment_col | sample_data_col
------------------------------+-----------------
 S000001                      | test1
 S000002                      | test2
 S000003                      | test3
(3 lignes)
```

How to use [sequences](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html)

How to  use [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createsequence.html) function.

Comment: Thanks for your response :). As FIFO i had voted Pavel Stehule Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create A sequence like below

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE seq_autoid
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 10000
```

Create A Function to generate *alpha numeric id*

```
create or replace function auto_id () returns varchar as $$
select 'SO'||nextval('seq_autoid')
$$ language sql
```

and try this example table

```
create table AAA(id text ,namez text)

insert into AAA values (auto_id(),'MyName')
insert into AAA values (auto_id(),'MyName1')
insert into AAA values (auto_id(),'MyName2')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response :). As FIFO i had voted Pavel Stehule Answer.